# using new array to store the sorted values in heap sort

Tags: arrays, c, heap, heapsort

I am currently studying about the algorithm about heap sorts, I wonder if it is possible to make a heapsort function that stores the sorted value in a new array (aside from the initial array where the unsorted values is stored) and not do anything to the initial array?

if you delete in heap sort, the root will switch with the last element right? so the last element will now have the address of the root, and the previous root will be placed in the last index/address in the array. After swapping the values, the size of the array will be decremented and the current address of the previous root will now not be considered as part of the array (because of decrease in array size).

So, what I want to know is a heapsort function that takes the initial array as the parameter. Im wondering if it is possible to take the element that will be deleted in the initial array and storing it in the new array in min heap order without doing anything to the initial array.

this is the code that Im studying from a website, im copying it here so that you can all see what im into

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct MinHeap MinHeap;
struct MinHeap {
    int* arr;
    // Current Size of the Heap
    int size;
    // Maximum capacity of the heap
    int capacity;
};

int parent(int i) {
    // Get the index of the parent
    return (i - 1) / 2;
}

int left_child(int i) {
    return (2*i + 1);
}

int right_child(int i) {
    return (2*i + 2);
}

int get_min(MinHeap* heap) {
    // Return the root node element,
    // since that's the minimum
    return heap->arr[0];
}

MinHeap* init_minheap(int capacity) {
    MinHeap* minheap = (MinHeap*) calloc (1, sizeof(MinHeap));
    minheap->arr = (int*) calloc (capacity, sizeof(int));
    minheap->capacity = capacity;
    minheap->size = 0;
    return minheap;
}

MinHeap* insert_minheap(MinHeap* heap, int element) {
    // Inserts an element to the min heap
    // We first add it to the bottom (last level)
    // of the tree, and keep swapping with it's parent
    // if it is lesser than it. We keep doing that until
    // we reach the root node. So, we will have inserted the
    // element in it's proper position to preserve the min heap property
    if (heap->size == heap->capacity) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot insert %d. Heap is already full!\n", element);
        return heap;
    }
    // We can add it. Increase the size and add it to the end
    heap->size++;
    heap->arr[heap->size - 1] = element;

    // Keep swapping until we reach the root
    int curr = heap->size - 1;
    // As long as you aren't in the root node, and while the 
    // parent of the last element is greater than it
    while (curr > 0 && heap->arr[parent(curr)] > heap->arr[curr]) {
        // Swap
        int temp = heap->arr[parent(curr)];
        heap->arr[parent(curr)] = heap->arr[curr];
        heap->arr[curr] = temp;
        // Update the current index of element
        curr = parent(curr);
    }
    return heap; 
}

MinHeap* heapify(MinHeap* heap, int index) {
    // Rearranges the heap as to maintain
    // the min-heap property
    if (heap->size <= 1)
        return heap;
    
    int left = left_child(index); 
    int right = right_child(index); 

    // Variable to get the smallest element of the subtree
    // of an element an index
    int smallest = index; 
    
    // If the left child is smaller than this element, it is
    // the smallest
    if (left < heap->size && heap->arr[left] < heap->arr[index]) 
        smallest = left; 
    
    // Similarly for the right, but we are updating the smallest element
    // so that it will definitely give the least element of the subtree
    if (right < heap->size && heap->arr[right] < heap->arr[smallest]) 
        smallest = right; 

    // Now if the current element is not the smallest,
    // swap with the current element. The min heap property
    // is now satisfied for this subtree. We now need to
    // recursively keep doing this until we reach the root node,
    // the point at which there will be no change!
    if (smallest != index) 
    { 
        int temp = heap->arr[index];
        heap->arr[index] = heap->arr[smallest];
        heap->arr[smallest] = temp;
        heap = heapify(heap, smallest); 
    }

    return heap;
}

MinHeap* delete_minimum(MinHeap* heap) {
    // Deletes the minimum element, at the root
    if (!heap || heap->size == 0)
        return heap;

    int size = heap->size;
    int last_element = heap->arr[size-1];
    
    // Update root value with the last element
    heap->arr[0] = last_element;

    // Now remove the last element, by decreasing the size
    heap->size--;
    size--;

    // We need to call heapify(), to maintain the min-heap
    // property
    heap = heapify(heap, 0);
    return heap;
}

MinHeap* delete_element(MinHeap* heap, int index) {
    // Deletes an element, indexed by index
    // Ensure that it's lesser than the current root
    heap->arr[index] = get_min(heap) - 1;
    
    // Now keep swapping, until we update the tree
    int curr = index;
    while (curr > 0 && heap->arr[parent(curr)] > heap->arr[curr]) {
        int temp = heap->arr[parent(curr)];
        heap->arr[parent(curr)] = heap->arr[curr];
        heap->arr[curr] = temp;
        curr = parent(curr);
    }

    // Now simply delete the minimum element
    heap = delete_minimum(heap);
    return heap;
}

void print_heap(MinHeap* heap) {
    // Simply print the array. This is an
    // inorder traversal of the tree
    printf("Min Heap:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<heap->size; i++) {
        printf("%d -> ", heap->arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void free_minheap(MinHeap* heap) {
    if (!heap)
        return;
    free(heap->arr);
    free(heap);
}

int main() {
    // Capacity of 10 elements
    MinHeap* heap = init_minheap(10);

    insert_minheap(heap, 40);
    insert_minheap(heap, 50);
    insert_minheap(heap, 5);
    print_heap(heap);
    
    // Delete the heap->arr[1] (50)
    delete_element(heap, 1);

    print_heap(heap);
    free_minheap(heap);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

if what im saying about is possible, can you please show me how? so that i can see and study the code. many thanks.

Comment: Just copy the entire initial array into the new array, then heapsort the new array.

Comment: can you show me how in code? so that I can see and study what is happening inside the function

Comment: You want to see code to copy the data from one array to a different array?

Comment: yes if possible. also I have researched about this heapsort function and I kept seeing them calling the heapify function inside the heapsort function. why is that? Im thinking that calling the heapify function inside the heapsort function is not necessary because heapify should be used on the initial array. I just want to get the deleted elements everytime an element will be deleted and store it in the new array (already sorted)

Comment: Heapsort takes an array as input, not a heap. So the first thing it does is turn that array into a heap, using heapify. The modification that you're talking about is just taking a copy of the array and heapsorting the copy, it's trivial.

Comment: so you want to see this code `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {different_array[i] = input_array[i];}` ?

Comment: And, removing elements from the heap and putting them into a different array instead of in the same array would be easy, and would produce a sorted array, but it would also modify the input array because removing an element from a heap changes the heap

Comment: Oh, removing an element from the initial heap is okay, it would make changes to the heap because of the decrease in array size. I want to see a heapsort function that will return a sorted values of the heap without modifying the initial heap (to do this, I'm thinking of creating a new array then store the sorted values inside and this new array will be returned by the heapsort function).

Comment: Well, not only the size changes, the data changes as well. Removing an element from a heap is definitely a destructive operation.

Comment: @User617290653251457439 create a new array. copy the numbers from the old array to the new array. heapsort the new array. return the new array.